# @Html classes for creating modal links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I know how to create ActionLinks.  I'm curious (to keep everything simiarl, if I can use the @HTML extensions to create a modal based link.

```
<a class="btn default" data-toggle="modal" href="#responsive">Create Board
</a>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Board", "EditBoards", "Forum", new { forumID = Request.QueryString["forumID"] }, new { @class = "btn default" })
```

The first link above how would I write that with Razor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Board", null, null, new { @class = "btn default", data_toggle = "modal", href = "#responsive" })
```

Data attributes can be added by replacing the hyphen "-" with an underscore "_".

Answer (score 1):

or better yet, go grab bootstrab mvc package from nuget, it's got all the helper methods to create bootstrap elements for your mvc view

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC/